# Put several scatterplots on each graph of subplots

Tags: r, plot, graph, plotly, r-plotly

I have a dataframe, which can be created with this code:

```
x = data.frame(metrics=c("type1", "type1", "type1","type1", "type1", "type1", "orders", "orders", "orders","orders", "orders", "orders", "mean","mean","mean","mean","mean","mean"), hr=c(6,7,8,6,7,8,6,7,8,6,7,8,6,7,8,6,7,8), actual=c(14,20,34,22,24,27,56,12,34,11,15,45,56,78,89,111,123,156), time=c("today", "yesterday", "today", "yesterday", "today", "yesterday"))
```

I want to visualise this data using plot_ly function. I want to create three subplots for each type of values in column "metrics". Also, on each subplot there must be two scatterplots for each type of value in column "time" (today, yesterday).

I did all, except making two scatterplots for each type of value in column "time" be different colours:

```
plot <- function(df) {
  subplotList <- list()
  for(metric in unique(df$metrics)){
    subplotList[[metric]] <- df[df$metrics == metric,] %>%
      plot_ly(
        x = ~ hr,
        y = ~ actual,
        name = metric,
        hoverinfo = "text",
        hovertemplate = paste(
          "<b>%{text}</b><br>",
          "%{xaxis.title.text}: %{x:+.1f}<br>",
          "%{yaxis.title.text}: %{y:+.1f}<br>",
          "<extra></extra>"
        ),
        type = "scatter",
        mode = "markers",
        marker = list(
          size = 18,
          color = "white",
          line = list(color = "black",
                      width = 1.5)
        ),
        width = 680,
        height = 420
      )
  }
  subplot(subplotList, nrows = length(subplotList), margin = 0.1)
```

I get this graph:

[image]

How to make these two scatterplots on each subplots be in different colours?

Comment: Please use the 'r-plotly' tag for question regarding the R package "plotly".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think you are after:

```
library(plotly)

x = data.frame(metrics=c("type1", "type1", "type1","type1", "type1", "type1", "orders", "orders", "orders","orders", "orders", "orders", "mean","mean","mean","mean","mean","mean"), hr=c(6,7,8,6,7,8,6,7,8,6,7,8,6,7,8,6,7,8), actual=c(14,20,34,22,24,27,56,12,34,11,15,45,56,78,89,111,123,156), time=c("today", "yesterday", "today", "yesterday", "today", "yesterday"))


plot <- function(df) {
  subplotList <- list()
  for(metric in unique(df$metrics)){
    subplotList[[metric]] <- df[df$metrics == metric,] %>%
      plot_ly(
        x = ~ hr,
        y = ~ actual,
        name = ~ paste(metrics, " - ", time),
        colors = ~ time,
        hoverinfo = "text",
        hovertemplate = paste(
          "<b>%{text}</b><br>",
          "%{xaxis.title.text}: %{x:+.1f}<br>",
          "%{yaxis.title.text}: %{y:+.1f}<br>",
          "<extra></extra>"
        ),
        type = "scatter",
        mode = "markers",
        marker = list(
          size = 18,
          color = "white",
          line = list(width = 1.5)
        ),
        width = 680,
        height = 420
      )
  }
  subplot(subplotList, nrows = length(subplotList), margin = 0.1)
}

plot(x)
```

[image: result]

[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63517586/make-subplots-of-plot-ly-graph-in-r/) for future readers.

Comment: thanks, and how could i move that table with labels right? cause on my original data it covers graphs

Comment: Please see [this](https://plotly.com/r/legend/#positioning-the-legend-outside-the-plot). You can also hide the legend.