# Сustomize R plotly plots colors in subplots

Tags: r, graph, plotly, r-plotly

I have a dataframe, which you can get with this code:

```
x = data.frame(metrics=c("type1", "type1", "type1","type1", "type1", "type1", "orders", "orders", "orders","orders", "orders", "orders", "mean","mean","mean","mean","mean","mean"), hr=c(6,7,8,6,7,8,6,7,8,6,7,8,6,7,8,6,7,8), actual=c(14,20,34,22,24,27,56,12,34,11,15,45,56,78,89,111,123,156), time_pos=c("today", "yesterday", "today", "yesterday", "today", "yesterday"))
```

Based on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521896/put-several-scatterplots-on-each-graph-of-subplots) I ended up with the following:

```
plot <- function(df) {

  subplotList <- list()
  for(metric in unique(df$metrics)){
    subplotList[[metric]] <- df[df$metrics == metric,] %>%
      plot_ly(
        x = ~ hr,
        y = ~ actual,
        name = ~ paste(metrics, " - ", time_pos),
        colors = ~ time_pos,
        hoverinfo = "text",
        hovertemplate = paste(
          "<b>%{text}</b><br>",
          "%{xaxis.title.text}: %{x:+.1f}<br>",
          "%{yaxis.title.text}: %{y:+.1f}<br>",
          "<extra></extra>"
        ),
        type = "scatter",
        mode = "lines+markers",
        marker = list(
          size = 7,
          color = "white",
          line = list(width = 1.5)
        ),
        width = 700,
        height = 620
      ) %>% layout(autosize = T,legend = list(font = list(size = 8)))
  }
  subplot(subplotList, nrows = length(subplotList), margin = 0.05)
}
```

and

```
plot(x)
```

gives me this:
[image]

As you see it builded subplots for each type of values in column "metrics" and also, on each subplot there are two scatterplots for each type of value in column "time" (today, yesterday). But they are different colours. How to make "today" and "yesterday" values same colour in each subplot? So there be only two types: "today" and "yesterday" in legend and each subplot be titled as "type1", "orders", "mean"

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved like so:

1. To get the same colors in all plots map `time_pos` on `color` instead of `colors`, .i.e `color = ~time_pos`. Using `colors` I set the color palette to the default colors (otherwise I get a bunch of warnings).
2. The tricky part is to get only two legend entries for `today` and `yesterday`. First map `time_pos` on `legendgroup` so that the traces in all subplots get linked. Second use `showlegend` to show the legend only for one of the plots, e.g. the first metric.
3. To add titles to the subplots I make use of `add_annotations` following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285729/how-to-give-subtitles-for-subplot-in-plot-ly-using-r)

   ```
   library(plotly)

   plot <- function(df) {
     .pal <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, "Set2")[c(1, 3)]
     subplotList <- list()
     for(metric in unique(df$metrics)){
       showlegend <- metric == unique(df$metrics)[1]
       subplotList[[metric]] <- df[df$metrics == metric,] %>%
         plot_ly(
           x = ~ hr,
           y = ~ actual,
           color = ~ time_pos,
           colors = .pal,
           legendgroup = ~time_pos,
           showlegend = showlegend,
           hoverinfo = "text",
           hovertemplate = paste(
             "<b>%{text}</b><br>",
             "%{xaxis.title.text}: %{x:+.1f}<br>",
             "%{yaxis.title.text}: %{y:+.1f}<br>",
             "<extra></extra>"
           ),
           type = "scatter",
           mode = "lines+markers",
           marker = list(
             size = 7,
             color = "white",
             line = list(width = 1.5)
           ),
           width = 700,
           height = 620
         ) %>% 
         add_annotations(
           text = ~metrics,
           x = 0.5,
           y = 1,
           yref = "paper",
           xref = "paper",
           xanchor = "center",
           yanchor = "bottom",
           showarrow = FALSE,
           font = list(size = 15)
         ) %>% 
         layout(autosize = T, legend = list(font = list(size = 8)))
     }
     subplot(subplotList, nrows = length(subplotList), margin = 0.05)
   }

   plot(x)
   ```

[image]

Comment: thanks, and could i change this colour? to choose something brighter?

Comment: Of course. You can define the colors as you like, e.g. `.pal <- c("green", "red")`.

Comment: my subplot titles are not visible. I see only arrows, though there is "showarrow = FALSE,", why it happens?